# How to recuperate user id (without duplicate) from DataFrame and store them in another Dataframe for later use

Tags: python, pandas

I have the table below in a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe:

```
date                   user_id     val1     val2       
01/01/2014 00:00:00        1       1790      12         
01/02/2014 00:00:00        3        364      15         
01/03/2014 00:00:00        2        280      10         
02/04/2000 00:00:00        5        259      24         
05/05/2003 00:00:00        4        201      39    
02/05/2001 00:00:00        5        559      54         
05/03/2003 00:00:00        4        231      69         
..
```

The table was extracted from a `.csv` file using the following query :

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['date','user_id', 'val1', 'val2']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, index_col = 'date')
```

I have to analyse the profile of each users and/or for the whole.
For this purpose, I would like to know how I can store at this stage all `user_id` *(without duplicate)* into another dataframe `df_user_id` *(that I could use at the end in a loop in order to display the results for each user id)*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused about your big-picture goal, but if you want to store all the unique user IDs, that probably should not be a DataFrame. (What would the index mean? And why would there need to be multiple columns?) A simple numpy array would suffice -- or a `Series` if you have some reason to need pandas' methods.

To get a numpy array of the unique user ids:

```
user_ids = df['user_id'].unique()
```

Comment: You are right: an array will be better but I was not sure for the type require in order to recuperate these data from a dataframe.